Śambhala City for resurgence of Kalkyavatar
Nowadays there are TV YouTube videos on the  Śambhala City. Sounds like the lost civilization of Atlantis.  This is common to Hindu/Buddhist ancestry ( Kalki Purana / Kala Chakra ) respectively.
Are there any other confirming pointed Vedic references to the esoteric  Śambhala, City from ancient Hindu sources, other than mythology ( some information is available in Telugu here) in some other Puranas? I ask this is such an important matter of faith about an expected future event.
Also do they reiterate point location, as well as affirmation for Kalki's future birth timing, Avatar appearance and invasion for Dushta samhar, and any timing for years AD etc.?
 Śambhala

question regarding cintāmaṇi is unrelated to Śambhala, it's better to have them as separate questions. Your question regarding Śambhala is kinda unclear. Do you just want references which point to its location or do you also want references which say Kalki would be born there? And what kind of references are you exactly looking on cintāmaṇi?

Thanks, edited per your suggestion.

Kālacakra tantra and comms. provide the rough (not exact) location of Śambhala, if you are interested in Bauddha sources. However, the geography in Kālacakra tantra is different from the Purāṇic geography.

Hindu saint Vishuddhananda called it Gyangunj. His disciples wrote a few things about Gyangunj. Gopinath Kaviraj wrote a book on Gyangunj based on the information he got from Vishuddhananda.

No. Obviously, for technical reasons, we will not have it in the Shastras..Puranas, yes they can guess. Even the Avatar knows it only at the last minute, Just In Time :-)! Or, the villains will plot to kill him right at birth..Hey, maybe they already are :-)
